# Fuzzy Lookup transformation connect Excel file in SSIS

Tags: excel, ssis, fuzzy

I am having trouble finding a reference that shows me how to connect Fuzzy Lookup in SSIS to an excel file instead of a database.

Searching the internet I have found this tip: [Excel Source as Lookup Transformation Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953531/excel-source-as-lookup-transformation-connection), but it provides a solution using Lookup not Fuzzy Lookup.

Can anyone help me setup Fuzzy Lookup with an excel data source please?

Comment: Changed the wording I hope to make things clearer and added some tags.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to use a Fuzzy LookUp with data coming directly from an Excel Source won't work because you have to connect to an OLE DB source for lookup. I would recommend dumping your data to a temporary or staging table to achieve this. With that you can create a table on run time and drop it once your done with the table. This also is handy in case you need the data else where in your loop.